# How can I find out how is a punctuation character form in UTF 8?

Tags: php, string, unicode, character-properties

I have a set of characters like

`.`, `!`, `?`, `;`,  (space)

and a string, which may or may not be UTF 8 (any language).

Is there a easy way to find out if the string has one of the character set above?

For example:

`这是一个在中国的字符串。`

which translates to

`This is a string in chinese.`

The dot character looks different in the first string. Is that a totally different character, or the dot correspondent in utf 8?

Or maybe there's a list somewhere with Unicode punctuation character codes?

Comment: Have you looked into http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unicode there are [character properties<sup>*PHP Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), for example Symbols, Letters and the like. You can search for any string of a specific class with [`preg_match`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_match) and the `u` modifier.

```
echo preg_match('/pP$/u', $str);
```

However, your string needs to be `UTF-8` to do that.

You can test this on your own, I created [a little script](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HW7kzx) that tests for all properties via `preg_match`:

```
Looking for properties of last character in "Test.":
Found Punctuation (P).
Found Other punctuation (Po).

Looking for properties of last character in "这是一个在中国的字符串。":
Found Punctuation (P).
Found Other punctuation (Po).
```

Related: [PHP - Fast way to strip all characters not displayable in browser from utf8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634941/php-fast-way-to-strip-all-characters-not-displayable-in-browser-from-utf8-strin/7635283#7635283).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `。` (U+3002, *IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP*) is a totally different character than `.` (U+002E, *FULL STOP*). If you want to find out whether a string contains one of the listed characters, you can use regular expressions:

```
preg_match('/[.!?;。]/u', $str, $match)
```

This will return either `0` or `1` and `$match` will contain the matched character. With this it’s important that your string in `$str` is properly encoded in UTF-8.

If you want to match any Unicode punctuation character, you can use the pattern `\p{P}` to describe the [Unicode character property](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode) instead:

```
/\p{P}/u
```

Answer (score 3):

you are not trying to transliterate, you are trying to translate!

UTF-8 is not a language, is a unicode character set that supports (virtually) all languages known in the world

what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",  "这是一个在中国的字符串。");
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",  "à è ò ù");
```

that not works with your chinese example