# Replace Invalid UTF-8, Not Replace

Tags: php, regex, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Evening,

I have HTML files that I am cleaning. These have some invalid Unicode characters that appear in my text editor like:

/B7

I want to replace these with either the character they should be, or a replacement character of my choice. For example, the /B7 character is a middot, but I want to replace it with a full-stop.

The function here: [PHP - Fast way to strip all characters not displayable in browser from utf8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634941/php-fast-way-to-strip-all-characters-not-displayable-in-browser-from-utf8-stri)

removes the invalid characters, but I am not keyed up enough on encoding to do anything more with it.

Comment: What do you mean by “/B7”? It’s three characters. What does your text editor (which?) render that way? How do you know what it “should be”? If “/B7” means “middot”, presumably U+00B7 “·”, what is invalid about it, and how does this relate to UTF-8?

Comment: I am using the text editor gEdit on Ubuntu.

I know what it should be as /B7 is a middot, but for some reason (I do not know why) instead of rendering as a middot, in gEdit it is just shown as '/B7' highlighted in red; and when I try to save the document in gEdit it tells me there are invalid characters.

I do not know what is invalid about it, as I am not sufficiently keyed up on character encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is encoded very likely in Windows-1252 (where `0xB7` decodes to `·`) and gEdit is decoding it as UTF-8 and shows the invalid UTF-8 bytes (`0xB7` is invalid in UTF-8 when outside a specific sequence) directly as their value I guess. You can fix the file in many ways but in PHP you could:

```
<?php
$file_contents = file_get_contents("brokenfile.txt");
$file_contents = mb_convert_encoding($file_contents, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
file_put_contents("brokenfile.txt", $file_contents);
```

The above script will decode the file as Windows-1252 and encode it as UTF-8.

Text editors allow you to specify what encoding to save files in usually in the 'save as' dialog or in some configuration. You should always configure your editor encodings before using it.

If you see `Â·` on your website after this conversion, that means you are telling the browsers that your stuff is in Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 etc. You must tell the browsers that your stuff is in UTF-8:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Thank you. The original file said it was some sort as ISO, and I was MB converting that; but as you have informed me, it is Windows-1252 and now all is well.

Thank you for your time and expertise.